# JBoss 7.1 - declare datasource and access via JNDI

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jboss7.x

I'am trying to migrate websphere 7  to JBoss 7.1 and i have several problem to configure my datasource, here is my whole config(database is oracle 10g) :

Jboss deployement looks fine

```
JBAS010400: Bound data source [jboss/datasources/xx3_oracle_tu_2]
```

My standalone-full.xml :

```
<datasources>
       <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/xx3_oracle_tu_2" pool-name="xx3_oracle_tu_2" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
               <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@************:1521:*****</connection-url>
               <driver>oracle</driver>
               <pool>
               </pool>
               <security>
                   <user-name>UD1XXBD</user-name>
                   <password>*******</password>
               </security>
           </datasource>
    </datasources>
    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc">
        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    </driver>
```

Seems ok about oracle driver:

```
JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 1.0)
```

Here is my bean in spring xml file :

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
      <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/xx3_oracle_tu_2"/>
      <property name="jndiEnvironment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">remote://localhost:4447</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">user</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">******</prop>
                <prop key="remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED">false</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.ejb.client.naming</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The only error i have is :

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jboss/datasources/xx3_oracle_tu_2 -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.jboss.datasources.xx3_oracle_tu_2
```

On Jboss web admin console, no problems datasource appears.
Also with jboss-cli script and this command line, everything seems ok :

```
jboss-cli.bat -c --command=/subsystem=datasources/data-source=xx3_oracle_tu_2:test-connection-in-pool
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [true]
}
```

I don't understand why this command line does not work :

```
jboss-cli.bat -c --command=/subsystem=datasources/data-source=java\:jboss\/datasources\/xx3_oracle_tu_2:test-connection-in-pool
```

Am i missing something about JBoss 7.1 JNDI configuration ?

Thanks by advance for your help !

EDIT : don't declare jboss/datasources and declare it like this in your standalone file and jboss-web file:

```
java:/xx3_oracle_tu_2
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK That command doesn't accept full JNDI references, it expects a datasource name.

You can view your datasource names with

```
/subsystem=datasources:read-resource(recursive=true)
```

Edit: ok, so the problem you have is with remote lookup.

If you look at [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/196876), you can see that unfortunately:

> Remote lookup of datasources is not supported in AS7.

Edit2: so you're not doing a remote lookup after all.

Both this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource"
    jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/xx3_oracle_tu_2"/>
```

and this:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/xx3_oracle_tu_2" />
</bean>
```

should do. JNDI env property you should not use, that's meant for remote lookups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! 
when i write this cmd :
-c --command=/subsystem=naming:jndi-view
jboss is a "javax.naming.Context", his children "datasources" is also a "javax.naming.Context and xx3_oracle_tu_2 is a "org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource".

It seems to be declared but i don't know how to access ! It is really frustrating !

Comment: @Aktarel based on your question you already got it working with datasource name ("xx3_oracle_tu_2"), so I'm not sure I fully understand what remains as an issue?

Comment: can't access to "xx3_oracle_tu_2" through spring xml bean conf. I'am using JndiObjectFactoryBean. Maybe i miss something in my jndi path or in my spring config.

Comment: @Aktarel ah, ok. I added a source to my answer, that's unfortunately not supported.

Comment: Okay. Is there an other way to bind a JB7 declared datasource to spring ?

Comment: @Aktarel Depends, is your Spring app deployed on jboss or on which server?

Comment: Spring app is on a JB7.1. Package is EAR with one jar and one war.

Comment: Ok here is the trick : 
I replaced java:jboss/datasources/xx3_oracle_tu_2 by java:/xx3_oracle_tu_2 in my standalone-full.xml and in my jboss-web.xml and everything works now.
Thanks for assisting me !

Comment: @Aktarel I never really understood if you have two different jboss servers, one containing the datasource and other the spring app, or just one jboss instance.

Comment: Only one instance (standalone mode)

Comment: in that case you have no need for jndiEnvironment property at all. Just do a regular JNDI lookup and everything should work.

Comment: something like `<jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/xx3_oracle_tu_2"/>` or jndiobjectfactorybean equivalent, `<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"><property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/xx3_oracle_tu_2" /></bean>`, without any jndi env. JNDI env definition is meant for remote lookups.

Comment: second one do not work. (and i don't know what's wrong !) 
I will try the first code.

Comment: the key thing should be dropping the jndienvironment property.